# No module named 'pafy'

Tags: python

```
sudo  pip3.6 install  pafy
Collecting pafy
  Downloading pafy-0.5.3.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pafy
  Running setup.py install for pafy ... done
Successfully installed pafy-0.5.3.1
```

It is Successfully installed pafy-0.5.3.1.

```
~$ python
Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:09:58) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import pafy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pafy'
```

Why no module named 'pafy'?

Comment: What does `type pip3.6` and `type python` tell you?  (assuming this is bash)

Comment: Since you are using Anaconda, first activate the environment, then do pip install. See [Does pip install packages into my conda environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54563932/does-pip-install-packages-into-my-conda-environment)

Answer (score 2):

You ran `pip` as `sudo` but you're running `python` as normal user. Programs run as normal user don't have rights to access `super-user`'s content (`sudo`).

To verify this, you can run `python` as super-user and try to import pafy.

```
$ sudo python
>>> import pafy
```

You should never use `sudo pip install`; you could overwrite important stuff.

Use `pip install --user <packagename>` or install and use `virtualenv`. I prefer [virtualenv](http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/).

Answer (score -2):

```
pip install pafy
```

This would work

Comment: ...unless `pip` is from the default Python 2.7 installation or some other Python version that isn't the same as what the OP is using (Python 3.6 from their Anaconda installation).

Comment: That does work for me with python 3.8

Comment: It's not about the version. It's which Python installation does `pip` refer to. It works for you because you either have only 1 Python 3.8 installation or you're activating the Python 3.8 environment properly. In the original question, OP is using Anaconda, so they should activate their conda env _first_, then do the pip install.