# pip installed module doesn't found - macOS

Tags: python, pip

I installed a Python module using pip. When I tried to import it, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Untitled.py", line 1, in <module>
import watson_developer_cloud
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'watson_developer_cloud'
```

What can I do to fix this?

I am using macOS Mojave 10.14.2 (beta), pip 10.0.1 (I also tried to upgrade it to 18.1, but after the install the version stayed the same).

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: You probably have several python installed, the system one and brew for instance. Make sure you select the proper one all the time.

Answer (score 1):

You probably installed it with sudo, so it's not accessible when you run the script without sudo. Anyhow, it's really messy to install modules directly. And it's dangerous to install modules to systems python.

Install a brew version of python and pip. then create a virtualenv and install your packages in it. It's much safer and portable.

Read this answer [No module named 'pafy'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44982951/no-module-named-pafy/44983589#44983589)

Please *don't* run the script as sudo to make it work, especially if you are not the one who wrote it. Use a virtualenv instead.

Comment: I hadn’t installed that with sudo

Comment: I see. Something else then. Try virtualenv anyway.