# Does pip install packages into my conda environment?

Tags: python, pip, conda

If I have created an environment with the 'conda create' command, then I activated it:

```
conda activate myEnv
```

Now if I want to install a package with 'conda install' to 'myEnv', but this package isn't in the conda repository. So I have to install it with the 'pip' command:

```
pip install newPackage
```

In this case, is the newPackage installed into 'myEnv', or it will be installed outside of the conda environment.

Comment: It will be installed in the environment. See: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.1/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#installing-non-conda-packages

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it should be installed in myEnv.

You can use `which pip` in Linux to check whether your environment's pip is called or the one from outside.

For the pip in your environment, it will be a path similar to `<path to anaconda environment>/bin/pip`.