# Convert PDF to HTML having issues

Tags: python

I am getting this error:
ImportError:

> No module named pdftotree

my code is:

```
import pdftotree

pdftotree.parse(pdf_file, html_path, model_type=None, model_path=None, favor_figures=True, visualize=False)
```

How I installed pdftotree:

```
sudo apt install python3-tk

pip install pdftotree
```

Comment: Do you use virtual environments?

Comment: which OS are you using? do you have multiple python versions?

Comment: Ubunt 16.04,yes i have python 2.7 and python 3.6

Comment: i install with pip3 install pdftotree,but same issue.

Comment: @san use sudo....

Comment: sudo also not working

Comment: import pdftotree
pdf_file='abc.pdf'
html_path='abc.html'
pdftotree.parse(pdf_file, html_path, model_type=None, model_path=None, favor_figures=True, visualize=False)

Not able to  create HTML from above code.

Comment: @buttercup,why downgrade my question.

Comment: @san I did not, I don't even have enough rep

Answer (score 1):

You might have multiple python environments. Or if you installed modules with sudo, they are not accessible to non-sudo users ([No module named 'pafy'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44982951/no-module-named-pafy/44983589#44983589)).

Install with pip3 and run with python3.

```
pip3 install --user pdftotree.
python3 file.py
```

Comment: import pdftotree

pdftotree.parse(pdf_file, html_path, model_type=None, model_path=None, favor_figures=True, visualize=False)

Comment: @san sorry, I'm not familiar with the library.